# Java store Long and Double in same map without precision loss

Tags: java

I need to store values in a Map where the values can be either Longs or Doubles. I can not afford any loss of precision that occurs when casting from one type to to the other.

I know I can make the values of type `BigDecimal` and convert my values to `BigDecimal` objects via `new BigDecimal(Long/Double.toString())`.

Is there a better or more efficient approach that I have not considered here?

Comment: Why convert at all? Use `Map<Foo, Number>` and you can store 'em both.

Comment: Because then I will need to have extra casts when retrieving objects

Comment: But you're willing to convert them and tolerate extra overhead incurred by `BigDecimals`? The choice is yours.

Comment: How exactly are you using them upon retrieval?

Comment: Good point. Thanks @Kayaman

Comment: Reconsider your design decision. This is more likely a bad design